# How do I merge dataframes on unique column values?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty new to dataframes. Suppose I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
user_id    username firstname lastname 
 123         abc      abc       abc
 456         def      def       def 
 789         ghi      ghi       ghi
 800         jkl      jkl       jkl        

df2
user_id    username firstname lastname 
 456         def      bbb       bbb 
 800         jkl      ccc       ccc
```

I want the resulting datafram:

```
df3
user_id    username firstname lastname 
 123         abc      abc       abc
 456         def      bbb       bbb 
 789         ghi      ghi       ghi
 800         jkl      ccc       ccc
```

Basically, I want to merge df1 and df2, and if the user_id is the same, I want to take the row from df2. How do I do this?

Comment: What is `print (df1.index)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with convert columns `user_id` to index if necessary:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('user_id')
df2 = df2.set_index('user_id')

df1.update(df2)
print (df1)
        username firstname lastname
user_id                            
123          abc       abc      abc
456          def       bbb      bbb
789          ghi       ghi      ghi
800          jkl       ccc      ccc
```

Comment: Wow, you're a lifesaver. Thank you! :D